# Apache Solr: What is a good strategy for creating a tag/attribute based search for an image

Tags: search, image, solr, search-engine

I recently read an article about YayMicro that descries how they used 
solr to search their photos.

I would like doing something similar (but on a smaller scale).

I have figured out how to have solr to search text files, but I would like to 
learn what the best way to associate images with semi structured/unstructured
text.  Do I create an xml file with an image link in it?

I basically want to input a search string and have it return a grid of images.

[Yay Micro Article Link](http://www.linuxtoday.com/it_management/2010090803035PRSV)